# Assign multiple variables with Scrapy Items at once

Tags: python, variables, scrapy, variable-assignment, assign

Is it safe in Scrapy spider to do this?

```
item1 = item2 = MyItem
```

If I change `item1['myfield']`, will `item2` gets changed as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on my own just a while ago, and it's not safe. Like what I expected before, it ends up having the same object value.

I wish another people can give a better explanation on multiple variable object assignment in Python.